# How to consume a method exported with MEF programatically?

Tags: mef

I'm exporting a method using MEF with the attribute [Export] and I need to consume this method using the Container (obtaining the method using GetExports).
GetExports returns an ExportedDelegate object that I have no idea how to extract the MethodInfo from.
Inspecting with the debugger I see it as a private property and I'm tempted to extract it using reflection but it doesn't feel like the right way of doing this.

Any ideas?

This problem is different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814839/how-to-export-import-functions-and-execute-them-with-mef). I'm not trying to use [Import], I have to obtain and consume the method from the Container.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export & import functions and execute them with MEF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814839/how-to-export-import-functions-and-execute-them-with-mef)

Comment: It's not what I need mate, I need to run this methods programatically, getting them directly from the container.

Comment: Why is that? Can't you just import it. What's stopping you?

Comment: It's a very specific situation: there is a centralized method that captures webrequests and we are basically associating a route to a class, that can be any class in the system that implements the interface I'm searching for. Basically I don't know what the signature of the method will be!

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys so that was a tricky one but I'm leaving here as a reference.

All you have to do is to cast the value returned from MEF to a ExportedDelegate and call CreateDelegate the right way:

This sets the Import we want:

```
var importDefinition = new ImportDefinition(e => true, obj.GetType().FullName, ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore, false, false);

var objectsWithMethods = container.GetExports(importDefinition)
                .Where(x => x.Value is IYourInterface)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList();
```

This gets the methods of the objects found above (iterate objectsWithMethods in a foreach using objectsWithMethod):

```
 var endPointsImportDefinition = new ImportDefinition(e => true, objectsWithMethod.GetType().FullName, ImportCardinality.ZeroOrMore, false, false); 
 var endPoints = container.GetExports(endPointsImportDefinition)
                        .Where(x => x.Value is ExportedDelegate)
                        .Select(x => x.Value)
                        .ToList();
```

And finally to get MethodInfo (which allows you to run the method) you use:

```
var endPointMethod = (endPoint as ExportedDelegate).CreateDelegate(typeof(Delegate)).GetMethodInfo();
```

What also could be:

```
var endPointMethod = (endPoint as ExportedDelegate).CreateDelegate(typeof(Delegate)).Method;
```

Hope it helps anyone!